# Working with multiple Chrome Profiles on the same browser?

Tags: puppeteer

At the moment I have 100+ browsers open using Puppeteer, each having a different Chrome Profile.

Is it possible to keep just one browser open, but give each tab a different Chrome Profile instead? This would improve the performance tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

Not even within a real browser, due to a Chrome Profile is tied to a browser instance not a browser tab.